# Rotate Images as in Word/Powerpoint

Tags: c#, winforms, image, rotation

I want to rotate an image in .Net application with the same look and feel as in MS word.

I am creating an application in which i need to rotate images. I provided the user with a control to make the images rotate.

But he wants the look and feel as in MS Word.

I have provided:

[image]

In the above image there is a track-bar which can be used for rotating the image.

But user wants it as:

[image]

The requirement is to only provide the [green] button for rotating the image. Any other option would be added functionality. :)

If anybody can provide ideas/ solution to this.

**Note:** Just to inform, rotation with track-bar is working perfect. I need a different mechanism for rotating.

If anybody wants me to upload the code, i can also do that.

Comment: Yes dude...i am using a seperate GUI for this, on which i am having a combobox to set the rotating angle. I would love to see a good solution.

Comment: This can be resolved in WPF in 2 lines of XAML and 3 lines of C# code, whereas it will require and endless hell of horrible hacks in winforms.